# nodejs child_process only get empty

Tags: node.js, git

when i use child_process exec/spawn for cmd

- `git gc`
- `git fsck --full`

will only get `''` for stdout/stderr

but it should return

```
$ git gc
Counting objects: 284, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (99/99), done.
Writing objects: 100% (284/284), done.
Total 284 (delta 169), reused 284 (delta 169)

$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (284/284), done.
```

what is wrong here
how do i get it

Answer (score 1):

Git output to stderr and not to stdout.
You have to redirect it to stdout in order to see it

```
git fsck --full | output.txt 2>&1
```

Than grab the content of the `output.txt` in your nodeJs application via `fs.readFile...`